# Using conditional selection to subset multiple variables in a dataset

Tags: r

I need to use conditional selection to create a subset of the data with records from the control group, weight > 440, and DMI > 13. I also need to find the cattle breed with the largest number of records in this subset of data.

The code I tried was:

```
> dat2[dat2$Treatment == "control" & dat2$Weight>440 & dat2$DMI >13]
```

but I am not sure that is correct.

```
> dput(head(dat2))
structure(list(Animal = 1:6, Weight = c(455.96, 418.05, 436.31, 
448.22, 418.35, 467.78), DMI = c(14.81, 17.63, 17.81, 15.01, 
15.42, 12.58), Breed = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = 
c("Angus", 
"Brahman", "Hereford", "Nelore"), class = "factor"), Treatment = 
structure(c(1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Control", "High", "Low"), class = ]
"factor"), 
Sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Castrate", 
"Female", "Male"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Animal", 
"Weight", "DMI", "Breed", "Treatment", "Sex"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: YOu need comma at the end.  Also, it is 'Control', instead of 'control' `dat2[dat2$Treatment == "Control" & dat2$Weight>440 & dat2$DMI >13,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the control with wheight and dmi, as @akrun pointed out:

```
subset <- dat2[dat2$Treatment == "Control" & dat2$Weight>440 & dat2$DMI >13,]
```

To get the cattle breed with the largest number of occurrences you can use `table`:

```
table(subset$Breed)
```